# An interesting problem having uneasy answers

Tags: functions, quadratics, parametric

> Consider $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}-\{0\}.$ A real valued function $f$ is defined as $f(x,y,z)=2^y\cdot3^z\cdot a^x\cdot b^y\cdot c^z+2^z\cdot3^x\cdot a^y\cdot b^z\cdot c^x+2^x\cdot3^y\cdot a^z\cdot b^x\cdot c^y$, where $x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z}$. Given that $f(1,0,0)=4$ and $f(2,0,0)=6$ then

> The possible value of $[a]$ $($where $[.]$ denotes the greatest integer function$)$ can be: Answer given is $0,1,2$

> The integral values of $\frac{1}{b}$ can be: Answer given is $1,2,3$

> If all possible values of $c$ satisfying given condition is $[p,q],$ then $4q-3p$ is equal to : Answer given is $2$

> The maximum value of $[a]^2+[b]^2-[c]$ $($where $[.]$ denotes the greatest integer function$)$ is: Answer given is $5$

My work: We can form two equations: $$a+2b+3c=4$$ and $$a^2+4b^2+9c^2=6$$
After this, I wasn't able to do anything. Then I checked if there are solutions to this on Wolfram Alpha and I got two set of real solutions.
$$a=\frac{2}{3},\:\:b=\frac{5}{6},\:\:c=\frac{5}{9}$$and
$$a=2,\:\:b=\frac{1}{2},\:\:c=\frac{1}{3}$$
In both the cases, the value of $[a]$ is either $2$ or $0$. It can't be $1$. Likewise, there are many loopholes in the other given answers also. So this can mean two things. Either the printed answers are wrong, or WA is not giving full solutions $($ though I highly doubt this case$)$.

Also, how can one get two or more set of real solutions$?$ Do we have to form a parametric equation or do we have to apply some advance algebra$?$

I actually require the method by which we can get values of $a,b,c$ and then I can review the printed answers.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use [Geogebra3D](https://www.geogebra.org/3d) to graph $x+2y+3z=4$(plane)  and $x^2+4y^2+9z^2=6$(ellipsoid). If you rotate the figure slowly, you’ll find that they intersect. So there are actually infinite real solutions corresponding to an ellipse in $\mathbb R^3$. $\\$ I ran a [check](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+x%2B2y%2B3z%3D4%2C+x%5E2%2B4y%5E2%2B9z%5E2%3D6) with WolframAlpha, and got a parametric solution in x (which implies infinite solutions), not just two sets of real values. Maybe you could add the link to what input you entered for WA?

Comment: @insipidintegrator Just remove the "solve" keyword from your search in WA

Comment: After looking at it closely, and after checking the ellipse and some calculations, I believe that they are the _ranges_ (starting and ending values, or min and max) of $x,y \ \text{and}\  z$. Note that there is a $-3x^2+8x-4=-(3x^2-8x+4)$ term under the square root, so that is defined only when $x\in [\dfrac 23, 2]$. After this, use the solutions panel at the bottom to calculate range of y and z.

Comment: @insipidintegrator how will one calculate the parametric form manually$?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to form quadratica in all variables then apply the condition of real roots. You will get  values of all variables having upper and lower bound.